# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException with jxl api when trying to copy content from one sheet to another

Tags: java, xls, jxl

Whenever I am trying to use template to create xls using jxl API running into weird ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.
Here is the snippet of code I am trying to use

```
private static void readWorkSheet()throws Exception{
            File file = new File("C:\\reports\\");
            Map template = new HashMap();
            File[] listFiles = file.listFiles();
            for(File file1:listFiles){
                if(file1.getName().endsWith(".xls")){
                    System.out.println(" ==> "+file1.getName());
                    Workbook workbookTemplate = Workbook.getWorkbook(file1);
                    template.put(file1.getName(), workbookTemplate);
                }

            }
            System.out.println("template "+template);
            Workbook templateWorkBook = (Workbook)template.get("TestReport.xls");
            Sheet readSheet = templateWorkBook.getSheet("Sheet1");

            WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("c://myfile_copy2.xls"));

            WritableSheet sheet = copy.createSheet("Test", 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < readSheet.getRows(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < readSheet.getColumns(); j++) {
                    Cell readCell = readSheet.getCell(j, i);
                    CellFormat readFormat = readCell.getCellFormat();
                    if(readFormat != null && readCell.getContents() != null && readCell.getContents() != ""){
                        WritableCell newCell = new Label(i,j,readCell.getContents());
                        WritableCellFormat newFormat = new WritableCellFormat(readFormat);
                        newCell.setCellFormat(newFormat);
                        System.out.println("details of cell ["+i+", "+j+"]"+" Name = "+readCell.getContents());
                        System.out.println("details of newCell ["+i+", "+j+"]"+" Name = "+newCell.getContents());
                        sheet.addCell(newCell);
                    }
                }
        }
            copy.write();
            copy.close(); 
        }
```

Not sure what I am missing in this !!!

Exception I am running into

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 56
    at jxl.biff.IndexMapping.getNewIndex(IndexMapping.java:68)
    at jxl.biff.XFRecord.rationalize(XFRecord.java:1667)
    at jxl.biff.FormattingRecords.rationalize(FormattingRecords.java:443)
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.rationalize(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:1023)
    at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.write(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:701)
    at com.jxl.test.JXLTest.readWorkSheet(JXLTest.java:83)
    at com.jxl.test.JXLTest.main(JXLTest.java:30)
```

Comment: The stack trace above does not appear to refer to any of your code. Did you include the complete stack trace from the exception?

Comment: Surround the code with try/catch. Are you sure the file is being created in C:\?

Answer (score 3):

I face the same problem. But it occurs only if I try to create more than one excel file by the same class. Means if i create two files by one junit test it occurs. If I do this by two separate unit test classes everything works fine. I am just searching for a kind of strong reference in the jxl code.
Until then I found a Workaround:

```
WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
wbSettings.setRationalization(false);
```

The problem occurs due to the FormattingRecords.rationalize() method. This setting above switches of the rationalization process. DateFormats and NumberFormats and so on will work **BUT** you will loose the WritableFonts for the cell format by doing this.

Stay tuned - maybe I will find more.

... I found more:
The main problem is that the jxl.biff.Fonts class is not reinitialized correctly and only contains the 4 default FontRecord entities. I dug a bit deeper and found that in the initialize method of the XFRecord class there is an if statement:

```
if (!font.isInitialized())
{
   fonts.addFont(font);
}
```

For the very first time a font is not initialized and will be added here successfully. For all other iterations the font is initialized and won't be added. No idea who holds the XFRecords and why it isn't refreshed correctly. But I found a working workaround:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void adjustUsedFonts(WritableWorkbook workbook) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    WritableWorkbookImpl workbookImpl = (WritableWorkbookImpl) workbook;
    Field fontsField = WritableWorkbookImpl.class.getDeclaredField("fonts");
    fontsField.setAccessible(true);
    Fonts fonts = (Fonts) fontsField.get(workbookImpl);
    Field fontsListField = Fonts.class.getDeclaredField("fonts");
    fontsListField.setAccessible(true);
    ArrayList<FontRecord> fontRecords = (ArrayList<FontRecord>) fontsListField.get(fonts);
    // just to get to know which fonts are available
    for (FontRecord fontRecord : fontRecords) {
        logger.info("found font: name={}; size={}", fontRecord.getName(), fontRecord.getPointSize());
    }
    // DON'T DO THIS HARDCODED LIKE THIS 
    // BUT CHECK IF YOUR FONTS ARE AVAILABLE AND ADD IF NOT
    if (fontRecords.size() == 4) {
        logger.info("only 4 fonts available - add necessary ones");
        fontRecords.add(tableDefaultFont);
    }
}
```

I put this method in front of calling the workbook.write method. And it works all fonts are available.
I know this is a hack and no good solution. This is why I will open an issue at their Ticket-Queue (the hack is only for those who cannot wait until the fix is available).

I used this version of jxl and it seemed to be the latest:
groupId: net.sourceforge.jexcelapi
artifactId: jxl
version: 2.6.12

ADDITION:
If you have more than one own font you will also need to add it in the right order by using its fontIndex. Otherwise fonts will be mixed up. I wrote a helpful method to find out the right index:

```
    private void determineFontIndizesOfOwnFonts(WritableWorkbook workbook) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    WritableWorkbookImpl workbookImpl = (WritableWorkbookImpl) workbook;
    Field frField = WritableWorkbookImpl.class.getDeclaredField("formatRecords");
    frField.setAccessible(true);
    FormattingRecords formRecords = (FormattingRecords) frField.get(workbookImpl);
    Field xfRecordListField = FormattingRecords.class.getDeclaredField("xfRecords");
    xfRecordListField.setAccessible(true);
    ArrayList<XFRecord> xfRecords = (ArrayList<XFRecord>) xfRecordListField.get(formRecords);
    logger.debug("amount of xfRecords: {}", xfRecords.size());
    for (XFRecord curXfRecord : xfRecords) {
        Font curFont = curXfRecord.getFont();
        if (curFont.equals(tableHeaderFont)) {
            logger.debug("font 'tableHeaderFont' info: idx={}, initialized={}, font[{}, {}px]", curXfRecord.getFontIndex(), curXfRecord.isInitialized(),
                    curFont.getName(), curFont.getPointSize());
            if (!fontIdxToName.containsKey(curXfRecord.getFontIndex())) {
                fontIdxToName.put(curXfRecord.getFontIndex(), tableHeaderFont);
            }
        }
        if (curFont.equals(tableContentFont)) {
            logger.debug("font 'tableContentFont' info: idx={}, initialized={}, font[{}, {}px]", curXfRecord.getFontIndex(), curXfRecord.isInitialized(),
                    curFont.getName(), curFont.getPointSize());
            if (!fontIdxToName.containsKey(curXfRecord.getFontIndex())) {
                fontIdxToName.put(curXfRecord.getFontIndex(), tableContentFont);
            }
        }
        if (curFont.equals(tableImportantOrFooterFont)) {
            logger.debug("font 'tableImportantOrFooterFont' info: idx={}, initialized={}, font[{}, {}px]", curXfRecord.getFontIndex(),
                    curXfRecord.isInitialized(), curFont.getName(), curFont.getPointSize());
            if (!fontIdxToName.containsKey(curXfRecord.getFontIndex())) {
                fontIdxToName.put(curXfRecord.getFontIndex(), tableImportantOrFooterFont);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then afterwards just add it in the right order see other method.

Comment: and it is always a good thing to do not use the default fonts because otherwise problems occur when the Fonts class tries to rationalize and finds a duplication. Especially for the hack above it is a good advice because otherwise an assertion can take place.

Answer (score 1):

I have just had this problem as well, both with version 2.4.2 and 2.6.12.

I solved it by no longer making any of the Fonts / DisplayFormats / WritableCellFormats objects static.

To be fair, I did find the solution here:
http://www.logikdev.com/2010/01/18/writablefont-doesnt-like-to-be-static/
Which also references the JExcelAPI FAQ:

> From http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/faq/
>
> “also, it’s important that you Do Not declare your cell formats as static. As a cell format is added to a sheet, it gets assigned an internal index number. If you have two threads (such as in a Web environment) writing two different spreadsheets, the format numbers will get confused and the resulting sheet could either be corrupted or incorrect.”

---

***Edit: little clarification based on comments.***

Initially my implementation was like this:

```
public class SomeExcelThing() { 
   private final static MY_FONT = new Font(); 

   public createCell() { 
      return new Cell(MY_FONT);
   }
}
```

Because it was now re-using the same Font object everytime a new cell was created, it gave that error. So then I changed it around to be:

```
public class SomeExcelThing() {
   public createCell() {
      return new Cell(new Font());
   }
}
```

So you should not make a constant out of Fonts, DisplayFormats, WritableCellFormats, as these would create these errors. So if you want to reuse a certain font, I would create a method to get the font you want, which would each time create a new font-object, instead of using a constant:

```
public class SomeExcelThing() {
   public createCell() {
      return new Cell(getMyFont());
   }

   private Font getMyFont() {
      return new Font();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think I'm having same problem, because I use WritableCellFormat and get that error. Can you please clarify how to not make them static? I'm not using static anywhere near there but are they by default static then?

Comment: @Deddy, it's been a couple of months now, so my memory is a bit hazy. But I recall I had something like this:  
  
`public class SomeExcelThing() {  
   private final static MY_FONT = new Font();  
   
     public createCell() {  
         return new Cell(MY_FONT);  
   }  
}`  
  
Because it was now re-using the same Font object everytime a new cell was created, it gave that error. So then I changed it around to be:  
  
`public class SomeExcelThing() {  
  
     public createCell() {  
         return new Cell(new Font());  
   }  
}`  
  
Ok, I give up trying to format...

Comment: @Debby, so to continue on (second comment because of max length), you should not make a constant out of Fonts, DisplayFormats, WritableCellFormats, as these would create these errors.
So if you want to reuse a certain font, I would create a method to get the font you want, which would each time create a new font-object, instead of using a constant:
`public class SomeExcelThing() {  
  
     public createCell() {  
         return new Cell(getMyFont());  
     }  

  private Font getMyFont() {
     return new Font();
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending that time! Now it's way more clearer, got it working (Y)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. I am using JXL library 2.6.12.
I was working with two different ".xls" files and was applying 3 different WritableCellFormat styles. When I was using the same three writable format objects in both the ".xls" cells, it was causing the problem.

**Solution:**
 I have created a method where I am creating different objects for WritableCellFormat. I called this method on both ".xls" workbook creation, separately. This worked as, both ".xls" files workbook creation is done with different objects of writable cell format.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
// make sure you only use .xls extension
    String filepath = "/Users/username/Downloads/Projects/Java/jExcelProject/reports/file.xls";
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(filePath));
```